# C++ char-array parameter contains weird characters on x86 compile

Tags: c++, arrays, char, 64-bit, visual-studio-2015

I'm quite new to C++ and I have to implement a Polybius cipher function.
I passed a char c-array as a parameter to my function.
I used a dummy string of "PROG" to test the code and it works perfectly when I compile it in x64(which was set as default by Visual Studio 2015 for some reason). However if I pass the array to the function in a x86 build, it contains weird characters for no appearant reason:
"PROG\x190§ÎæÏX1"

Heres my code:

```
void createPolybiusMatrix(const char keyphrase[]) {
    //Keyphrase contains "PROG" on x64 but "PROG\x190§ÎæÏX1" on x86!
    //Do Stuff
}

int main() {
    char passphrase[] = {'P','R','O','G'};
    //Everythings fine here, passphrase contains "PROG" on both platforms.
    createPolybiusMatrix(passphrase);
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas? I'm still quite new to C++ and this confuses me like hell!?

Comment: `void createPolybiusMatrix(const char keyphrase[])` is as good as `void createPolybiusMatrix(const char* keyphrase)` make it `void createPolybiusMatrix(const char* keyphrase, std::size_t size)`

Comment: Interesting, could you elaborate further why I should include std::size_t size as a parameter??

Comment: @KevinKuegler Because in C (and C++), you can't pass arrays to functions; they decay to pointers. So the length is lost. The `size_t` parameter allows you to specify the length. This is an alternative to the "C strings" approach in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C strings need to be null-terminated. In order for your program to work correctly, you need to use:

```
char passphrase[] = {'P','R','O','G','\0'};
```

Answer (score 1):

The char array is not null-terminated, so if the byte following `'G'` is not 0, you'll overflow and print out garbage. This is technically undefined behavior.

To print the char array as you would a string, you need to null-terminate it.